# How to get regexreplace to ignore a character based on what comes before it and replace it when those conditions are not met in Google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I have texts in which all of the apostrophes (‘) and quotation marks (“) are coming out incorrectly as question marks. e.g. *I?m writing to send my wishes and congratulate you on your engagement*. I’m using regexreplace in Google sheets to replace the question marks with apostrophes: =REGEXREPLACE(A1, "?", "'")

The problem is that I don’t want to replace actual (i.e. correct) question marks with apostrophes. So, I need to be able to make regexreplace ignore true question marks. We could define a true question mark as 1. one that comes before two spaces (in the case of one at the end of a paragraph) and 2. before a space and a capital letter (in the case of one at the end of a sentence within a paragraph). In practice rule 2 will capture some apostrophes (those coming before proper nouns not at the start of a new sentence), but it’ll be rare enough not to matter much.

Any ideas on how can I put these rules for ignoring real question marks into regexreplace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A2,"\?([\w\.])","'$1"),"\?( [a-z])","'$1")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike Steelson - it works pretty well.
But it doesn’t work on these three:

sisters’ bag, 

sisters?.,

the ?Derby? thing.

Here's the sheet I'm using: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TrQxKdYKQqD_IDZ-A_aIqDSftMskFWAa8y0KSVDD9p8/edit?usp=sharing

Any idea how to modify it? (Sorry, I’m a novice…)

Comment: Is this new proposal ok for you?

Comment: That's great - thank you. I was trying to figure it out myself and I came up with this: =REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A2,"\? ([a-z])","' $1"),"\?([A-Za-z])","'$1"), "\?(\.)","'$1"), "\?(\,)","'$1"). The only difference is that mine can handle a comma after the apostrophe too. Wouldn't have got even close without your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: OK, I've accepted it - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A5, "?", "'"), " '|' ", " ? "))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot player0 - it works on some things but I should have mentioned that some of the apostrophes in the text will be correct, so it shouldn’t change apostrophes into question marks, only the other way around. This formula works both ways.